# How to seperate DateTime as a class prop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to seperately display Date and Time in two different select fields (SelectList). User should choose a date and then choose a corresponding time from a cascading list. But in my class my property has a type of DateTime.

The problem is that when i create a SelectList , where 3rd arg is in "", c# considers it as a string, so I can't use methods like ToString ('d') etc.

class.cs:

```
public partial class OrderTime
    {
        public OrderTime()
        {
            CnOrder = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public decimal Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderTimeDate { get; set; }
        public bool OrderTimeStatus { get; set; }
        public decimal SalesCenterId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> CnOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

controller:

```
public IActionResult Checkout()
        {

            var ordertimelist = _ordertime.All.Where(x => x.OrderTimeStatus == true).Where(a => a.SalesCenterId == a.Id).ToList();
            var salescenterslist = _salescenters.All.Where(x => x.Status == true).ToList();
            ViewBag.OrderTimeId = new SelectList(ordertimelist, "Id", "OrderTimeDate");
            ViewBag.SalesCenterId = new SelectList(salescenterslist, "Id", "CenterName_AZ");
            return View();

        }
```

Comment: You know `DateTime`, has both a `Date`, and a `Time` property ?

Comment: if u mean DateTime.Date which displays date and time set to default 00:00:00 then yes i know but i need time not to be displayed at all

Comment: _Displaying_ the date in a particular way (eg. without the time showing) is a formatting / presentation issue to be tackled in your view, not in your model

Answer (score 0):

As for `Date` you can look into [this](https://github.com/supersonicclay/csharp-date) custom Date struct on GitHub.
For `Time` you will probably need to implement your own Time struct that is pretty much the similar to Date struct.